# There is a logical or mathematical symbol for compatibility/incompatibility?

Tags: notation

Exists a symbol in logic or mathematics to relate two or more compatibility or incompatibility conditions? I dont want to specify a determined area of study (topology, algebra, etc...) I just want to know about this topic in a broad sense, if it exists something like this and the related area.

This is just for curiosity, sorry if my question is so undefined or broad but I dont have any clue about this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with compatibility or incompatibility conditions?

Comment: @Newb: by example that two things dont fall in contradiction. I remember that studying lineal systems with matrix we study if an determined equation system is compatible or not, i.e., if it have solutions or not... but I never see a notation to express this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Sheffer stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke), introduced in 1913 and written $\mid$, is often described as asserting that two propositions are incompatible. (For example, [Whitehead and Russell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica) describe it this way.) The assertion $$A\mid B$$ means precisely that $A$ and $B$ cannot both be true.

Answer (score 2):

In [forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)) - a technique in set theory - incompatibility is denoted by "$\perp$". (Interestingly this disagrees with how wikipedia [uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability) the notation . . .)

I think whatever notation you use, you will need to define explicitly (if, say, you are writing a paper).